# How to create a matrix choosing the highest values to assign values of a column that compensate those of a row?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, math, matrix

What I need is to do this part of the method implementation of Vogel's approximation algorithm in Python for the maximization problem with assignment matrix updates.

[image]

Here my code:

```py
objetivo = "max"
# objetivo = "min"

#tabla_datos = [[3, 6, 6, 9, 35], [9, 2, 3, 7, 50], [1, 5, 4, 5, 40], [45, 20, 30, 30, 0]]
tabla_datos = [[5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 500], [2, 5, 3, 1, 0, 330], [2, 4, 0, 1, 1, 120], [140, 220, 360, 80, 150, ]]


# Create profit table
tabla_ganancias = [fila[:-1] for fila in tabla_datos[:-1]]

# Get the number of rows and columns of tabla_ganancias
m = len(tabla_ganancias)
n = len(tabla_ganancias[0])

# Calculate the number of assignments, in this case is 7
# In this case   m + n - 1 = 3 + 5 - 1 = 7 assignments
nro_asignaciones = m + n - 1

# Calculate supply and demand
oferta = sum(tabla_datos[i][-1] for i in range(m))
demanda = sum(tabla_datos[-1][j] for j in range(n))

print(nro_asignaciones) # in this case 7
print(oferta) #in this case 950
print(demanda) #in this case 950

if objetivo == "max":
```

Starting from this code, propose the Vogel algorithm, that is, since the problem is to "maximize" the first allocation was made in the box with the highest profit, which is 6, for the second allocation or second sale there are several options, since they all have a profit of 5 , we choose one of them , for the third sale there are two boxes with 5 in the same row , we choose one of the 5 , then since that factory still has tons to sell we choose the last box with a profit of 5 , for the fifth assignment remains as the box with the highest profit, that of 3, the sixth sale to the box with profit 1, and finally the last sale in the box that has no profit.

Go making the assignments, and print one by one. **These would be the outputs that you would need to obtain, that is, to print every time you make an assignment.**

```py
#build this matrix of zeros with the dimensions m and n
# Initialize assignment matrix with zeros
tabla_asignaciones = [[0] * n for _ in range(m)] # m x n 
#in this case...
tabla_asignaciones = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#In this case   m + n - 1 = 3 + 5 - 1 = 7 assignments

#assignment 1
tabla_asignaciones = [[0, 220, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#assignment 2
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#assignment 3
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#assignment 4
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#asignacion 5
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 330, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#assignment 6
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 330, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 90]]

#assignment 7
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 330, 0, 0], [0, 0, 30, 0, 90]]


#Finally staying like this...
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 330, 0, 0], [0, 0, 30, 0, 90]]
```

Comment: @Stef Yes, the question is... How do I do the assignments? I know that for something like this I should go through the matrix and verify the values of the profits (as it is to maximize it should go from the highest to the lowest), and so on until exhausting the demand values in the supply values

Comment: This looks like a minimum-cost maximum-flow problem.

Comment: @Stef Yes, It is a cost reduction problem (in some books they are called transport optimization problems) using this algorithm as a means of optimization. In my code in the question, the first thing I did was calculate the number of rows m and the number of columns n, then use the formula m + n - 1 to find the number of assignments to perform, and using the value still stored in m and in n create the array of zeros where the assignments will be placed.

Comment: What I couldn't get to do (and that's what I asked in the question) is that this algorithm performs the evaluation of the assignments based on the gain values of the m x n matrix.